# Enum types that are not equality comparable

Tags: haskell, equality, enumerable

Enum represents types that can be mapped to or from integers.

Integers can be tested for equality.

Is there an instance of Enum which doesn't want Eq?

Comment: I guess all the standard instances of `Enum` are also instances of `Eq` -- I can't think why that should not be the case.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question - do you want an example where it would be useful?

Comment: I once created a data-type for terminal-colors and used the from/toEnum functions to create the terminal escape code, since Eq was not needed anywhere I didn't derive it. If for some reasons you don't want equality in production code you can put orphan instances in your testing code - where you most definitely need Eq

Comment: @epsilonhalbe But you could have, and it would have made an awful lot of sense

Comment: I guess, there is no such use case. Even `Data.Void` has an Eq instance.

Answer (score 3):

Only `Enum` would not be enough to provide equality tests, since `Int` is bounded. Let's say we had the following function, which you probably had in mind.

```
eqEnum :: Enum a => a -> a -> Bool
eqEnum x y = fromEnum x == fromEnum y
```

Now we can generate two `Integer` that don't coincide:

```
ghci> eqEnum 0 (2 + 2 * toEnum (maxBound :: Int))
True
```

We can also check `Double`:

```
ghci> eqEnum 3.0 pi
True
```

Well, whoops. `Enum` doesn't give rise to a correct `Eq` instance. We can even go a little bit further and create an instance of `Enum` for a type that cannot have an `Eq` instance:

```
newtype Foo = Foo { unFoo :: Integer -> Integer }

instance Enum Foo where
  fromEnum (Foo f) = fromEnum $ f 0
  toEnum   n       = Foo (+ toInteger n)
  succ             = Foo . succ . unFoo -- not necessary
  pred             = Foo . pred . unFoo -- not necessary
```

We can use that bogus instance to enumerate the family of functions `F_n(x) = x + n`:

```
> map ((\f -> unFoo f 0) . toEnum) [0..100]
[0,1,2,...,100]
```

However, whether two `Foo` functions are the same cannot be decided. And, as it is with `Double`, there are many `Foo` values that aren't actually recoverable with `toEnum . fromEnum`:

```
ghci> toEnum . fromEnum $ pi :: Double
3.0
ghci> let f = toEnum . fromEnum $ Foo (const 0) :: Foo
ghci> unFoo f 0
0 
ghci> unFoo f 1 -- not constant anymore
1
```

The basic problem is that `Enum` has no laws. You need to convert from and to `Int`. But in the end, that's not very surprising, giving that they were [originally meant for `[x..y]`](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/haskell/haskell-intro-html/stdclasses.html) (aka `enumFromTo x y`).